# What I can do to achieve this kind of smtp proxy

Tags: proxy, smtp, vps, spam, filter

I'm providing VPS services and I don't want my IP addresses spoiled by spammers. What I want to achieve here is to route all the outbound traffic to some sort of smtp proxy server which will just let other traffic go through while analysing email packages against spams.

I know there are some good open source spam filter solutions there like spamassassin but these filters will need a MTA in front of it such as postfix. But for the VPS, I can't do this. So can someone shed some light on it please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

depends on your MTA you can have it to relay through an alternative mail gateway

sendmail:

```
SMART_HOST
```

postfix:

```
relayhost
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but we're VPS provider and we can't control our customer's machines to set this. So we need some sort of technics to filter the IP packages.

Comment: you can filter outbound connection on firewall and have all users to reconfigure it to go through specific smtp gateway only.

Comment: How can I filter outbound connection? What kind of software can I use? Thanks.